# Initial value of radio button in Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, radio-button, default

I am trying to set the initial value of my Django form. However, I am not able to do it. I have tried using initial and googled a lot.

My code for the form is

```
class xyz(forms.Form):
random_text = forms.CharField(label='random_label')
CHOICES=[(1,'abc'),
         (2,'def')]
selection = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect())
```

And the code for my template is

```
<div class="text-center">
    {% for choice in form.selection %}
        <div class="radio-inline">
            {{ choice }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

And the code for the views of the same is

```
form = xyz(request.GET)
```

Answer (score 0):

The initialization should be done like this:

```
form = xyz(initial={'selection': 1})
```

Or:

```
form = xyz(initial=request.GET)
```

Comment: how about the _request.GET_ part then? Where do I include that one?

Comment: I tried doing what you suggested. However, it didnt help either. Any other way?